# How to SSH from MacOS terminal to Ubuntu 22.04. No matching host key type found

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, sshd, ubuntu-22.04

I'm not able to login to Ubuntu 22.04 which I newly installed from MacOS terminal.

Here is the error I get while trying to SSH to ubuntu

```
QWERTY-M-91FL:~ qwerty$ ssh mnbv@16.67.45.123
Unable to negotiate with 16.67.45.123 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is caused by the server and the client not having a common accepted type of host key. Most probably this is caused by a new SSH server version and an old SSH client version. Ubuntu 22.04 bundles with OpenSSH 8.9, while ssh-rsa (the most used key type) has been disabled since OpenSSH 8.8. From the [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8):

> This release disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm by
> default. This change has been made as the SHA-1 hash algorithm is
> cryptographically broken, and it is possible to create chosen-prefix
> hash collisions for <USD$50K [1](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8)

**The best approach would be to update your ssh client version.** Seriously. It might be an easy approach to change the server's settings, but as stated by the OpenSSH developers, hash collisions are very easily found for older ssh-rsa, which could completely break your security and allow for man-in-the-middle attacks.

---

Another approach is to tell the server to generate older host key types ([manual](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html)).

1. Get a list of all supported host key types on the client:

   ```
   mtak@client:~$ ssh -Q sig
   ssh-ed25519
   sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
   ssh-rsa
   rsa-sha2-256
   rsa-sha2-512
   ssh-dss
   ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
   ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
   ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
   sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
   ```
2. Pick a supported host key (signature) type and add that to the HostkeyAlgorithms list on the server:

   In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add and/or set:

   ```
   HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
   ```

   (note that I haven't tested this. I don't have an SSH client old enough to run into this issue)

Answer (score 3):

Note that you encounter this error due to old host key algoriths being disabled. So be warned as you proceed:

You can override the host key algorithm using

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+rsa-sha2-512 mnbv@16.67.45.123
```